# PHP Get Array From URL

Tags: php, arrays, parsing

I'm trying to make a PHP array from a URL string.

My code:

```
$files = urldecode($_POST['files']); // The String
error_log($files); // Output to see how it looks like
parse_str($files); // parse...
error_log($files[0]); // See the result
```

My Error_log after I run the script:

```
file[]=U07ttCL89
f
```

(If someone is wondering why I output with `error_log` - it because I can't see the output)

Why is it returning `f` after parsing?

The `$_POST['files']]` syntax is :

```
file[]=XXXXXXXXX&file[]=YYYYYYYY&file[]=ZZZZZZZZZ
```

Comment: I just read one note: `This function automatically urldecodes values (not mentioned in the docs).`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo. The new var is `file` not `files` ;)

```
error_log($file[0]); // See the result
```

You can access a string like an array.
If you use $files[0], you ouput the first char of the string, which is stored in $files.
In your case it is `file[]=XXXXXXXXX&file[]=YYYYYYYY&file[]=ZZZZZZZZZ`

Comment: How didn't I notice that?? I feel dumb. Thank you very much for the help! Appreciate it!!!.

Comment: Yeah, it was not easy. I didn't see it at first, too :)

Answer (score -1):

Use this:

```
$files = array();
$count = count($_POST['files']);
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
  $files[] = $_POST['files'][$i];
}
```

UPDATE: The answer is actually simpler

```
$files = $_POST['files'];
```

Comment: It outputs the same - `f`

Comment: Do me a favor and run the line: **error_log(json_encode($_POST))** and post the response in a comment below